# How can we use Multiple ng-if methods in a same div in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Is there is any possibility for using Multiple ng-if methods in a same div 
example:

```
<div ng-if="condition1">
<!-- code to render -->
 <div ng-if="condition2">
 <!-- code to render -->
</div>
 <div ng-if="condition3">
 <!-- code to render -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aZpVpz

Comment: yes you can use multiple ng-if conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple ng-if conditions

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-if="true">
<!-- code to render -->
  div1
 <div ng-if="true">
 <!-- code to render -->
   div2
</div>
 <div ng-if="false">
   div3
 <!-- code to render -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aZpVpz

Comment: How could we implement a validation function inside the ng-if .. for example: <div ng-if="showFirst"><form>have to validate the form inputs </form></div> After validating the First div it has to be display the second div <div ng-if="showSecond"><form>have to validate the form inputs </form></div>

Comment: i just gave check() function return value true and check2() return value as false...you can write your validation part in those functions and return true or false  that will do :)